# How to see how many nodes a process is using on a cluster with Sun grid engine?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am (trying to) run R on a multicore computing cluster with a Sun grid engine. I would like to run R in parallel using the MPI environment and the snow / snowfall parLapply() functions. My code is working at least on my laptop, but to be sure whether it does what it is supposed to on the cluster as well, I have the following questions.

If I request a number of slots / nodes, say 4, how can I check whether a running process actually uses the full number of the requested CPUs? Is there a commend that can show details about the CPU usage on the requested nodes for a process?

Comment: Is this [your framework](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/manuals.html)? If so, perhaps `qstat` would be for you (`qstat - show the status of Sun Grid Engine jobs and queues`).

Comment: Yes, I think so. `qstat` shows the running jobs with the allocated number of cores / slots, but does not show how many of those are actually used by the process

Comment: Using `qstat`, I doubt it. You can use qhost to monitor load of each load, and try to infer if your process is using the correct number of CPU, but this is not ideal either.  Also, with `qstat -j <job_id>` maybe you can infer CPU usage by seconds used versus actual runtime? In general, if you test your code and it works in parallel on your laptop, it should work in parallel on GridEngine. Is there something that makes you suspect otherwise?

Comment: Yes, the `qstat -j jobid` idea might work. I just thought there would maybe be a simple option for qstat or another command that I was not aware of. I just want to make sure that I use the computing cluster correctly, has I have already been rebuked on some occasions for submitting to wrong queues and also for requesting a parallel environment of 4 cores when my process only used one (reason was my stupidity as I only copy-pasted scripts for qsub from others). This also lead me to believe there might be an obvious option for accessing the number of occupied cores by a process

Comment: As you have seen, GE doesn't validate the cores the job *actually* uses and just reserves cores based on parameters specified by the queue config or by `qsub`.  The best you can do is use an environment variable to specify the number of cores you pass to `qsub` and pass this parameter into your program as well, so you are always getting a match between what you request via GE and what is actually used by the program.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify that the cluster workers really started on the appropriate nodes, I often use the following command right after creating the cluster object:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, Sys.info()['nodename'])
```

This should match the list of allocated nodes reported by the `qstat` command.

To actually get details on the CPU usage, I often ssh to each node and use commands like `top` and `ps`, but that can be painful if there are many nodes to check. We have the Ganglia monitoring system set up on our clusters, so I can use Ganglia's web interface to check various node statistics. You might want to check with your system administrators to see if they have set anything up for monitoring.